# Cannot have images of tables side by side without margins

Tags: html, css, image

I have images of Excel tables that I have to add on an HTML page. I have 6 images, where the first four don't need to be side by side (but need not to have space between them), but the last two have to be side  by side (with no margins between them) as that table was originally in landscape mode. I have tried different methods but none of them work. I am using HTML and CSS. The code is below. Any help will be very appreciated. I am using Eclipse Juno for the development.

```
 //***Html file

 <div class="crop">
   <img src ="QATables/image1.png">
   <img src ="QATables/image2.png">
   <img src ="QATables/image3.png">
   <img src ="QATables/image4.png">     
   <img src ="QATables/image5.png" border="0"><img src ="QATables/image6.png" border="0"/>


 </div> 

  //*****CSS file

  .crop img {width:850px; height:791px; margin: 0px;border-bottom:0}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add two classes that you can use for styling, one for those that shouldn't be side by side, and one for those that should.

```
<div class="crop">
   <img src ="QATables/image1.png" class="vertical">
   <img src ="QATables/image2.png" class="vertical">
   <img src ="QATables/image3.png" class="vertical">
   <img src ="QATables/image4.png" class="vertical">     
   <img src ="QATables/image5.png" class="horizontal">
   <img src ="QATables/image6.png" class="horizontal">
</div>
```

Then you do something like this:

```
.vertical {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block; /* Force images to be shown vertically */
}

.horizontal {
    float: left;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubWu6/1/)

Comment: @T4000 You'll have to elaborate on that. In what way did it not work?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my desk for an hour. All I did was to create the two classes "horizontal" and "vertical" in the CSS file, and did the few changes in the .html file. Unfortunately, I did not have a different result, as if no changes were made in the those two files.

Comment: @T4000 If you inspect the images in the dev tools of your browser. Have the rules been applied to the element? Are you referencing the CSS-file properly?